# Slow query optimisation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

We have a performance issue with a specific SQL query and we're trying to figure out how could we improve here. It's execution time on is about 20 - 100 seconds!

Here is the query and it's explain:

```
SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"
  WHERE "jobs"."status" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  ORDER BY "jobs"."due_date" ASC
  LIMIT 5;


Limit  (cost=0.42..1844.98 rows=5 width=2642) (actual time=16927.150..18151.643 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_jobs_on_due_date on jobs  (cost=0.42..1278647.41 rows=3466 width=2642) (actual time=16927.148..18151.641 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (status = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 595627
 Planning time: 0.205 ms
 Execution time: 18151.684 ms
```

We are using PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on AWS RDS.

In a table we have ~500K rows. Fields realted to the query are:

- due_date(timestamp without time zone, can be null)
- status(integer, not null)

We have the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_jobs_on_due_date ON public.jobs USING btree (due_date)
CREATE INDEX index_jobs_on_due_date_and_status ON public.jobs USING btree (due_date, status)
CREATE INDEX index_jobs_on_status ON public.jobs USING btree (status)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX jobs_pkey ON public.jobs USING btree (id)
```

Thank you in advance,
- Jack

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT  j.*
FROM "jobs" j
WHERE j."status" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY "jobs"."due_date" ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

The "obvious" index is on `(status)`.  But that may not help.  The goal is to get rid of the sorting.  So, you can rewrite the query and use an index `jobs(status, due_date)`:

```
select j.*
from ((select j.*
       from jobs j
       where j.status = 1
       order by j.due_date asc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select j.*
       from jobs j
       where j.status = 2
       order by j.due_date asc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select j.*
       from jobs j
       where j.status = 3
       order by j.due_date asc
       limit 5
      ) union all
      (select j.*
       from jobs j
       where j.status = 4
       order by j.due_date asc
       limit 5
      )
     ) j
order by due_date
limit 5;
```

The subqueries should each use the composite index.  The final sort would then be on (at most) 20 rows, which should be fast).

EDIT:

Here is a related idea, with the same index:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM (SELECT  j.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.status ORDER BY j.due_date ASC) as seqnum
      FROM "jobs" j
     ) j
WHERE j.status in (1, 2, 3, 4) AND seqnum <= 5
ORDER BY j.due_date ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

This can use the index for the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation.  That might require a full table scan of the table.  But, the final sort will be limited to 20 rows, so the final sort is eliminated.

Comment: The solution you provide works, but in our case, we have a lot of queries of such kind (which choose from multiple statuses). Also, those queries usually have a lot of additional filters and conditions. So it will be quite tricky to build that kind of unions.

Is there a way to force using the statuses index there - looks like it's slow because it is not used. Or other possible solutions? Thanks!

Comment: @JackJuiceson . . . It is not about forcing the use of the `status` index; it is about the sort afterwards.